# Pick out the correct statements

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Pick out the correct statements from the following list:
>
> a. A homomorphic image of a UFD (unique factorization domain) is again a
>   UFD.
>
> b. The element $2 ∈ \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{−5}]$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{−5}].$
>
> c. Units of the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{−5}]$ are the units of $\Bbb{Z}.$
>
> d. The element $2$ is a prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{−5}].$

I think (d) is not correct. But I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: i think d is not correct.but not sure about the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**  For (a) note that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$.
For (b) and (c), use properties of norm. You are right about (d), since $2$ divides $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: and $2$ does not divide $1+\sqrt{-5}$ or $1-\sqrt{-5}$

Comment: @Belgi $\rm\,\ 2\nmid 1\pm\sqrt{-5}\color{#C00}{\ \ in\ \ \Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque - this is important, thanks for adding this! (this is what I meant but I forgot to mention)